# IOrderedQueryable Skip and Take

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-5, iqueryable

I have the following abstract class which all of my Repositories inherit from:

```
abstract class RepositoryBase<T> {
    void Add();
    void Delete();
    void SaveChanges();
}
```

I wanted to add another method for automatically paging an `IQueryable<T>` and returning a `List<T>` from the results:

```
protected List<T> Paginate(IQueryable<T> content, int? skip, int? take)
{
    if (skip.HasValue) content = content.Skip(skip.Value);
    if (skip.HasValue && take.HasValue) content = content.Take(take.Value);
    return content.ToList();
}
```

But, `Skip` requires that the source by `IOrderedQueryable<T>`. I tried changing the method signature to:

```
Paginate(IOrderedQueryable<T> content, int? skip, int? take)
```

But `Skip` returns an `IQueryable<T>` so I receive the error `Cannot convert source type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<T>' to target type 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable<T>'`

How do I force the implementing class to send my method an `IOrderedQueryable<T>` and get my paginate method to work?

Comment: Which version of `Skip` requires (at compile-time) that the source be `IOrderedQueryable`? `Queryable.Skip` doesn't...

Comment: @JonSkeet LINQ to Entites - `The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'` - unless I'm misunderstanding the error.

Comment: That's odd - because if you've got `using System.Linq;` it should pick up this method - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357513(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @JonSkeet EF raises runtime errors if the query has no inherent reliable order

Comment: @MarcGravell: Right. It's not *at all* clear from the question that the OP was talking about an execution-time error. It now is, but I'd expect it to be fine at execution time so long as it really is ordered.

Comment: As a side note, it would feel very odd to me if I called `Paginate(query, null, 20)` and it didn't apply the take. I don't thing the `skip.HasValue` check on the second line is intuitive or obvious.

Comment: I apologise if I wasn't clear enough. I thought that given the error, I was being asked to ensure the source was of `IOrderedQueryable` which is why I mentioned in the question

Comment: @MarcGravell I was under the impression I needed to call `Skip` in order to call `Take` although I've no idea where I got that form. Will take that on-board, thanks

Comment: @RGraham to confirm: you can use `Take` without `Skip`

Comment: Just tried and updated code accordingly, thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you should might want to make `Paginate` still take an `IOrderedQueryable<T>` to validate at *compile-time* that you've started with something that's ordered - but you don't then need to assign back to the same variable. For example:

```
protected List<T> Paginate(IOrderedQueryable<T> content, int? skip, int? take)
{
    // Different variable type so that we can assign to it below...
    IQueryable<T> result = content;
    if (skip.HasValue) result = result.Skip(skip.Value);
    if (skip.HasValue && take.HasValue) result = result.Take(take.Value);
    return result.ToList();
}
```

And as Marc notes, it would probably be better to change the `Take` line to:

```
if (take.HasValue) result = result.Take(take.Value);
```

Comment: Just to complicate things: some *other* providers do *not* require the original query to have an explicit order... all fun and games; it would work fine with L2S without an `OrderBy` / `IOrderedQueryable<T>`

Comment: I marked this as the answer as I want the Repository implementation denote exactly what order the resultset should be in, so updating the signature to `IOrderedQueryable<T>` makes sense

Comment: @MarcGravell: I'd say that enforcing this within an internal API is a good idea anyway - even if you *can* skip in an arbitrary order, it probably isn't a good idea :)

Answer (score 4):

The `Queryable.Skip` and `Queryable.Take` methods do not require this, but some providers (I'm thinking "EF" mainly) do insist on it; in which case the solution is simply: make sure the original query *has an order*. For example:

```
var query = {whatever}.OrderBy(x => x.Id); // identity column? why not...
var page = Paginate(query, ...);
```